# Question on the proof of Sard's theorem regarding the nesting of vanishing partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, smooth-manifolds

I am reading the proof of Sard's theorem from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.
In the proof, we have $F:U \subset \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ a smooth map and denote $C \subset U$ to be the set of critical points of $F$. Then he defines a decreasing sequence of subsets $C \supseteq C_1 \supseteq C_2 \supseteq \dots$ as follows:
$$C_k = \{x\in C:\text{for } 1\le i \le k, \text{all ith order partial derivatives of $F$ vanish at x} \}.$$

Why is $C_{k+1}\subset C_k$? Isn't it possible to have a function whose $k+1$th  derivative is zero but $k$th is not?

Comment: Notice that the set definition stipulates that *all partials up to order $k$* are zero, not just the partials of order $k$. This induces a trivial set inclusion.

Comment: @whpowell96 Oh you are right this is just trivial by definition.